# How do I get TexForm to work on the command line? (Windows only)

Tags: windows, command-line

I try to run:

```
wolframscript -code "TeXForm[""2+2""]"
```

But I end up with:

> ```
> TeXForm[2+2]
> ```

I am using Windows.

From my research, I understand that Mathematica can't display this properly on the command line. I also understand that I need to do something tricky, but I have no idea how Linux, or "xvfb-run" works.

Can someone please provide step-by-step instructions on how to solve this issue for us poor Windows users?

Comment: It is spelled TeXForm but one set of quotes is enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this?

```
 wolframscript -code HoldForm[1+1] -format TeXForm

 wolframscript -code Range@10 -format TeXForm

 wolframscript -c ConstantArray[0,{10,10}] -format TeXForm
```

[image]

if on `Windows`, the Command Line `cmd` should be run as `Administrator` to have `wolframscript` executed. get more info on how to use `wolframscript` under `Windows` by this way.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`TeXForm` seems to work on the FrontEnd level so we cannot use it in the command line. Instead, codes below:

```
wolframscript.exe -code "Covert``TeX``ExpressionToTeX @
Inactive[Integrate][Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}]
"
```

does work.

Cause `` ` `` is an escape character of PowerShell, I wrote ``` `` ``` to get a single backquote. In other (most) shell-langs,
`` Covert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX `` is just enough.

Try:

```
Information["Convert`*TeX*"]
```

in Mathematica to get more symbols about *-TeX Convert.